# MATLAB: error: In A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and  I must be the same

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a code for piecewise linear interpolation using the code my teacher gave the class--it's worth noting that the teacher seemed to have trouble with the equation inside the for loops--and I've run into the error "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same." after exiting the loops. I've already looked up the error and know that comes from trying to fit the elements of one array into another of a different size, but I'm not familiar with matrices in MATLAB. Can someone help me understand where my error is coming from?

Here's the code:

```
EDU>> pts = [-5:1.25:5];
EDU>> x = [-5:.01:5];
EDU>> length(pts)

ans =

    9

EDU>> x = x';
EDU>> size(x)

ans =

    1001           1

EDU>> fpts = 1./(1+pts.^2);
EDU>> plot(fpts)
EDU>> deltax = 10/1000

deltax =

    0.0100

EDU>> 1000/8

ans =

   125

EDU>> newF = zeros(size(x));
EDU>> for k = 1:9
for j = 1:125
newF((k)*125+j) = (fpts(k) + ((x*k*125) + j) + (x*k*125))/(1.25*(fpts(k)- pts(k)));
end
end
???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
```

Answer (score 2):

For example `k` starts from 1, so `k-1` starts from 0, and then you have `fpts(k-1)`. This is where you get the error.

Edit: This was the correct answer to the question until the question changed (to 100% new question).

Hint (for further proceeding):
If one complex line gives you several errors and you do not know where the error comes from, try splitting it into several lines.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
newF((k)*125+j) = (fpts(k) + ((x*k*125) + j) + ...
                  (x*k*125))/(1.25*(fpts(k)- pts(k)));
```

`x` is a vector (size 1x1001) which makes the right hand side a vector whereas the left hand side of the line. So you need to index `x` as well ie calculate newF for single element of `x`.